# Closed form for elements of inverse matrix of lower triangular matrix of any size

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

If we have a lower triangular matrix $$A=\left(\begin{array}{rrrrr}a_{1,1}&0&0&\cdots&0\\a_{1,2}&a_{2,2}&0&\cdots&0\\a_{1,3} &1_{2,3}&a_{3,3}&\cdots&0\\ \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{1,n}&a_{2,n}&a_{3,n}&\cdots&a_{n,n}\end{array}\right)$$ does there exist a formula for a certain element of $A^{-1}$ in terms of its coordinates, the elements of $A$, and $\det(A)$?

Given such a matrix of any particular size, we can calculate each term of the inverse matrix by expanding the multiplication and solving. For instance, if $A$ is a $3\rm x 3$ matrix, then we have $$A^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{lll}
\frac 1{a_{1,1}}&0&0\\
-a_{1,2}\over a_{1,1}a_{2,2}&\frac 1{a_{2,2}}&0\\
a_{1,2}a_{2,3}-a_{1,3}a_{2,2}\over a_{1,1}a_{2,2}a_{3,3}&-a_{2,3}\over a_{2,2}a_{3,3}&\frac 1{a_{3,3}}
\end{array}\right).$$ We can, by similar methods, calculate exact formulae for any specific value of $n$. These formulae seem tantalizingly as if there is some general formula that holds for all $n$ for each entry, but I am unable to find one. Does such a formula exist?

**Note:** I am aware of a few other questions on this subject, but none of them seem to answer this; however, I know very little linear algebra I may have just failed to understand them.

Comment: What is $b_{n,k}$?

Comment: @RobertLewis The element of $A^{-1}$ in the $n$th row, $k$th column. Editing question to clarify.

Comment: I see now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $M_{x,y}$ be the element of $M$ at coordinates $(x,y)$, $M_{(x_0:x_1),(y_0:y_1)}$ be the $(x_1-x_0)\times(y_1-y_0)$ submatrix $N$ such that $N_{x,y}=M_{x-x_0,y-y_0}$, and $M_{(x_0:x_1)+(x_2:x_3),(y_0:y_1)+(y_2:y_3)}$ be the block matrix (with not necessarily square blocks) $\begin{bmatrix}M_{(x_0:x_1),(y_0:y_1)}&M_{(x_2:x_3),(y_0:y_1)}\\M_{(x_0:x_1),(y_2:y_3)}&M_{(x_2:x_3),(y_2:y_3)}\end{bmatrix}$.

$$\begin{aligned}A^{-1}_{x,y}&=(-1)^{x+y}\cdot\frac{\det(A_{(x:y-1),(x+1:y)})}{\det(A_{(x:y),(x:y)})}\\
&=(-1)^{x+y}\cdot\frac{\det(A_{(x:y-1),(x+1:y)})}{\prod_{i=x}^y(A_{i,i})}\end{aligned}$$

Proof:

Recall that $M^{-1}=\frac{\mathrm{adj}(M)}{\det(M)}$, and $\mathrm{adj}(M)=\mathrm{cof}(M)^T$ (where $\mathrm{cof}$ is the cofactor matrix), so $A^{-1}_{x,y}=\frac{(-1)^{x+y}\cdot\det(A_{(1:x-1)+(x+1:n),(1:y-1)+(y+1:n)})}{\det(A)}$.

Note that similarly to how a triangular matrix's determinant is the product of the elements along its diagonal, there is a trick for computing determinants of "almost-triangular" matrices (in this case almost-lower-triangular). For each cell on or above the main diagonal, shine two rays from it, leftwards and downwards, onto the diagonal. Complete these into a square on the other side, and merge overlapping squares (ie. those sharing cells) into larger squares. For instance,$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\color{red}1&\color{red}1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&\color{red}1&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&\color{red}1&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&\color{red}1&0&\color{red}1&0\\
1&1&1&1&\color{red}1&0&\color{red}1\\
1&1&1&1&1&\color{red}1&0\\
1&1&1&1&1&1&\color{red}1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\color{yellow}1&\color{red}1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&\color{yellow}1&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&\color{red}1&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&\color{yellow}1&\color{yellow}0&\color{red}1&0\\
1&1&1&1&\color{yellow}1&\color{yellow}0&\color{red}1\\
1&1&1&1&1&\color{yellow}1&\color{yellow}0\\
1&1&1&1&1&1&\color{yellow}1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\color{yellow}1&\color{red}1&0&0&0&0&0\\
\color{green}0&\color{yellow}1&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&\color{red}1&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&\color{yellow}1&\color{yellow}0&\color{red}1&\color{green}0\\
1&1&1&\color{green}1&\color{yellow}1&\color{yellow}0&\color{red}1\\
1&1&1&\color{green}1&\color{green}1&\color{yellow}1&\color{yellow}0\\
1&1&1&\color{green}1&\color{green}1&\color{green}1&\color{yellow}1
\end{pmatrix}
$$The determinant of the matrix is the product of the determinant of the square matrices along this partitioning of the diagonal, $\det\left(\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\right)\cdot\det\left(\begin{pmatrix}1\end{pmatrix}\right)\cdot\det\left(\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&0\\1&1&0&1\\1&1&1&0\\1&1&1&1\end{pmatrix}\right)$

Consider the $n=8$ case, and computing the value of the cell at $(2,6)$. $$\begin{pmatrix}
M_{1,1}&0&0&0&0&\color{red}0&0&0\\
\color{red}{M_{1,2}}&\color{red}{M_{2,2}}&\color{red}0&\color{red}0&\color{red}0&\color{red}0&\color{red}0&\color{red}0\\
M_{1,3}&\color{blue}{M_{2,3}}&M_{3,3}&0&0&\color{red}0&0&0\\
M_{1,4}&\color{blue}{M_{2,4}}&M_{3,4}&M_{4,4}&0&\color{red}0&0&0\\
M_{1,5}&\color{blue}{M_{2,5}}&M_{3,5}&M_{4,5}&M_{5,5}&\color{red}0&0&0\\
M_{1,6}&\color{blue}{M_{2,6}}&\color{blue}{M_{3,6}}&\color{blue}{M_{4,6}}&\color{blue}{M_{5,6}}&\color{red}{M_{6,6}}&0&0\\
M_{1,7}&M_{2,7}&M_{3,7}&M_{4,7}&M_{5,7}&\color{red}{M_{6,7}}&M_{7,7}&0\\
M_{1,8}&M_{2,8}&M_{3,8}&M_{4,8}&M_{5,8}&\color{red}{M_{6,8}}&M_{7,8}&M_{8,8}
\end{pmatrix}$$After the red cells are removed, we partition it into squares$$\begin{pmatrix}
\color{red}{M_{1,1}}&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
M_{1,3}&\color{yellow}{M_{2,3}}&\color{red}{M_{3,3}}&\color{green}0&\color{green}0&0&0\\
M_{1,4}&\color{green}{M_{2,4}}&\color{yellow}{M_{3,4}}&\color{red}{M_{4,4}}&\color{green}0&0&0\\
M_{1,5}&\color{green}{M_{2,5}}&\color{green}{M_{3,5}}&\color{yellow}{M_{4,5}}&\color{red}{M_{5,5}}&0&0\\
M_{1,6}&\color{green}{M_{2,6}}&\color{green}{M_{3,6}}&\color{green}{M_{4,6}}&\color{yellow}{M_{5,6}}&0&0\\
M_{1,7}&M_{2,7}&M_{3,7}&M_{4,7}&M_{5,7}&\color{red}{M_{7,7}}&0\\
M_{1,8}&M_{2,8}&M_{3,8}&M_{4,8}&M_{5,8}&M_{7,8}&\color{red}{M_{8,8}}
\end{pmatrix}$$The determinant of this adjugate matrix can be found similarly. Besides the large matrix in the numerator, all falling outside of the $(x:y),(x:y)$ square cancel out with those in the denominator, to provide the final expression of$$\begin{aligned}M^{-1}_{2,6}&=\frac{M_{1,1}\cdot\det\left(\begin{pmatrix}M_{2,3}&M_{3,3}&0&0\\M_{2,4}&M_{3,4}&M_{4,4}&0\\M_{2,5}&M_{3,5}&M_{4,5}&M_{5,5}\\M_{2,6}&M_{3,6}&M_{4,6}&M_{5,6}\end{pmatrix}\right)\cdot M_{7,7}\cdot M_{8,8}}{M_{1,1}\cdot M_{2,2}\cdot M_{3,3}\cdot M_{4,4}\cdot M_{5,5}\cdot M_{6,6}\cdot M_{7,7}\cdot M_{8,8}}\\
&=\frac{\det\left(\begin{pmatrix}M_{2,3}&M_{3,3}&0&0\\M_{2,4}&M_{3,4}&M_{4,4}&0\\M_{2,5}&M_{3,5}&M_{4,5}&M_{5,5}\\M_{2,6}&M_{3,6}&M_{4,6}&M_{5,6}\end{pmatrix}\right)}{M_{2,2}\cdot M_{3,3}\cdot M_{4,4}\cdot M_{5,5}\cdot M_{6,6}}\end{aligned}$$